# Cross validating logistic GAM using CVgam

Tags: r, cross-validation, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I have an ecological data set, whereby sediment mud content (%) (i.e. the continuous explanatory variable) is thought to be explaining the spatial distribution (i.e. presence/absence) of various estuarine benthic macroinvertebrate taxa (i.e. the binary response variable). Below is a subset of the data (actual data consists of >1400 replicates) for a single taxon, where the response is 'Bin' and the single predictor is 'Mud' and 'Estuary' is considered a random effect.

```
Estuary       Mud   Bin
FW            0.1   0
FW            0.3   0
FW            0.2   0
FW            2.1   0
POR           7.1   0
FOR           11.4  0
JRE           25.5  1
JRE           33.6  1
JRE           44.6  1
JRE           55.6  1
JRE           63.6  1
FW            76.6  1
FW            87.6  1
FW            90.6  1
FW            93.6  1
```

Here's the GAM model which used the `mgcv` package (and was conditioned on the 1400+ data points):

```
aa1.estuary<-gam(Bin~s(Mud,bs="ps", k=6) + s(Estuary, bs="re"),family=binomial, gamma=1,data=sample)
```

Here's the Cross validation step, which used `CVgam` in the `gamclass` package, but returned the error below when `Estuary` was included as a random effect:

```
aa1.val <- CVgam(formula=Bin~s(Mud, bs="ps", k=6) + s(Estuary, bs="re"), data = sample, nfold = 10, debug.level = 0, printit = TRUE, method = "GCV.Cp",cvparts = NULL, gamma = 1, seed =100)
Error in X[ind, ] : subscript out of bounds
```

To check, `Estuary` was omitted, generating the following output:

```
aa1.val <- CVgam(formula=Bin~s(Mud, bs="ps", k=6) , data = sample, nfold = 10, debug.level = 0, printit = TRUE, method = "GCV.Cp",cvparts = NULL, gamma = 1, seed =100)
     GAMscale    CV-mse-GAM  
     0.1491      0.1499
```

Hence I have two related questions: (1) whats causing the error when `Estuary` is included in the cross-validation step? and (2) do the above estimates of `GAMscale=0.1491` and `CV-mse-GAM =0.1499`seem too close to one another to be realistic?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Usually the smoothing is not added to categorical variables. In particular if you try to solve the same problem with the GAM package it requires a minimum number of unique values for each smoothed variable.

Comment: Any idea of syntax for a non-smoothed categorical random effect?

Comment: just replace + s(Estuary) with + Estuary

Comment: so without the bs="re" term, `Estuary` is still considered a random effect? I tried this and deviance explained remained similar but AIC was lower with `s(Estuary, bs="re")` term compared to `Estuary`..